# Pricing defaultable asset with finite maturity

Tags: stochastic-processes, futures, brownian-motion, default

Assume a stochastic process $X_0 = 0$ and $X_t = \nu t + \sigma W_t$  where $W_t$ is standard Brownian motion and $\nu$ is a drift (can have $\nu \leq 0$ if necessary, but prefer it to be general), and $\sigma > 0$.  Furthermore,

- Let  $\underline{X} < X_0$ be an exogenously given default threshold.
- Define the first passage time as the random stopping time: $T = \inf\{ 0 < t \mid X_t=\underline{X} \}$.
- Define $0 < \bar{T} < \infty$ as a terminal time.

An asset pays out as follows:

- If default has not happened by the terminal date (i.e., $T > \bar{T}$), the asset pays $p(X)$
- If default does occur (i.e. $T \leq \bar{T}$), the asset pays $0$
- Everything is discounted at rate $r> 0$

---

**QUESTION:**
Given a $\nu,\sigma^2,\bar{T}, X(0),\underline{X}$, how do we price this asset?

**Is this standard?**
More abstractly (and forgive my poor knowledge of terminology),  is this linear combination of standard debt and equity instruments?  Looks a lot like a some weird combination of a stock market futures contract and a credit default swap, but I can't figure it out?  If it is standard, then we may be able to just add up the solution from some standard formulas.

**Attempts at solution:**
My gut tells me this can be written recursively with a Bellman equation such as:
$$
r V(t,X) = \nu V_X(t,X) + \frac{1}{2}\sigma^2 V_{XX}(t,X) + V_t(t,X)
$$
With boundary values,
$$
V(t,\underline{X}) = 0, \text{for all $t < \bar{T}$}
$$
and 
$$
V(\bar{T},X) = p(X), \text{for all $X \geq \underline{X}$}
$$

And if we could solve PDE, then the price is: $V(0,X(0))$.  Is this correct, or are the boundary values incorrect because they let the $X$ dip below $\bar{X}$ and then go above to gain potentially be higher at $\bar{T}$?

If this is the correct PDF and boundary values, I can attempt a direct solution.

Comment: Might this be some sort of defaultable forward contract?

Comment: Seems to me as a continuously monitored down-and-out barrier (with payout $p()$) + one-touch put option (with coupon $d$). You could indeed price it with the BS PDE along with appropriate boundary conditions or, simply Monte Carlo. I guess there should even exist a closed form expression under your simple ABM modelling assumption.

Comment: Thank you so much for your comments.  This is for some theory, so if I need numerical techniques to solve it, then I have written down the problem wrong (or, maybe, the theory is wrong!)

Comment: @Quantuple I made a small change to remove the $d$, and now it pays nothing if $X$ hits the boundary.  Does this change things?  Is this now isomorphic to pricing a future on with one-sided default?  I looked up "barrier options" but this looks like a future, rather than an option, to me?

Comment: Have a read through section 0.5 here: https://www.google.be/url?sa=t&source=web&rct=j&url=https://people.maths.ox.ac.uk/howison/barriers.pdf&ved=0ahUKEwjwrMvAw7jRAhVCAsAKHbwADtAQFggeMAE&usg=AFQjCNFwqEKeiAvbDX6tgDceMI59GBG2rw. Does it help you? Although pricing is conducted under GBM modelling assumptions you should have no problem translating what's done to your ABM dynamics

Comment: @Quantuple Thank you so much for the response.  Unless I am missing something, I don't think this is an option, because there is no max anywhere in my payoff at time $\bar{T}$?  Is there some sort of a barrier on futures? or defaultable future? (again, thank you for your understanding of my lack of knowledge of the terminology)

Comment: (just to be clear, the person valuing the asset is not able to default, it is the other side of the market)

Comment: From the information you give, nothing states whether the payout $p(X_{\bar{T}})$ is linear or not. When talking about a (down and out barrier) "option" I was indeed assuming non-linearity. This instrument is indeed "standard" (at least it has been studied a lot).

Comment: @Quantuple The payout is definitely not linear (and is without corners).  Maybe I have missed what an option in is generality.  The problem I have with the barrier option is that the pricing formulas seem to have some sort of an option to exercise (i.e. a max) and the down-and-out condition is connected to the underlying price (which it isn't in my case).

Comment: After looking at the literature, is there a chance this is a "forward contract with counterparty risk"?